# Does Apple publish in app purchase system status anywhere? Is it possible to determine if/when their systems are down?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

On occasion it appears that Apple's servers related to in-app purchase become unavailable or start responding with failure.  I've seen both their receipt verification service (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt) and the services that respond to SKProductsRequest API calls go down.

Does Apple post any status for their in app purchase related backend systems?

Is it possible to determine if/when their systems are down?

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering how you determined such problems for the end users? Or are you seeing this problem in the simulator?

Comment: I've had end users email in that they are having problems which I've been able to reproduce on my own iPhone.  It's a rare occurrence, but it's happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Check this you can get all status of apple server

Comment: Are there any RSS feeds available for us for the apple status pages? (Status pages from Google often have RSS feed) I am pretty sure nobody wants to actively go to the website to check if the status is ok; we all want to be alerted only when something happens.